# Save russian in mysql by java

Tags: java, mysql, internationalization, flyway

When I try to execute a query via flyway from my java application, the data in my database are saved in incorrect form.
Example is the query below:

```
INSERT INTO `table_lang` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('14', 'русский');
```

The name in table_lang after execution for id= 14  is

> p??????

So I thought that the problem was due to the input file, and I tried to insert in the query my name converted with various charsets

- русский
- \u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439  as UTF-16
- \xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9 as UTF-8

and I tried to change the charset and the collate of my table of interest respectively

- CHARACTER SET = utf16 , COLLATE = utf16_general_ci ;
- CHARACTER SET = utf8 , COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ;
- CHARACTER SET = utf16 , COLLATE = utf16_general_ci ;
- CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 , COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ;

None of these approaches work. Do you know how it can be solved?

Answer (score 2):

- Use `CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
- You may also need to add `characterEncoding=UTF-8` in your JDBC connection string.

With these settings I'm able to write and retrieve Russian and also Turkish charachers on my system.

You may also be interested in [How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with the server... Which server are you ? I set my global time zone with this command :
`set global time_zone = '+3:00';`
and tried your command :
`INSERT INTO table_lang (id, name) VALUES ('14', 'русский');`
and i got the appropriate output :
`id name 14 русский`
Try my command and tell if it works : )

Comment: what a time-zone has to do with a charset?